# Xhtml option is not available in eclipse

Tags: xhtml, eclipse-kepler, java-server

While creating JSF project, xhtml option is not available in my eclipse kepler...
I have also tried downloading JBoss Tools(Kepler)4.1.2 Final
So please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to [Eclipse Luna](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), Kepler is getting old now...